# How to Verify WorkSheets in a GROUP are empty or contain no data?

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to find a way to check if any sheets in sheets group are empty or contain data.

I tried using this, but doesn't seem to work.

```
.Sheets(Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")).select
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection.UsedRange.Cells) = 0 Then 
  MsgBox "All Sheets empty!"
  Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: you would rather need to loop `for each` sheet in your sheets array.

Comment: The reason `WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells)` does not work is that it counts cells on the _Active Sheet_ (which will be one sheet even if mor than one are selected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

If sheets "1" to "9" are adjacent with no other sheets in between, use:

```
Sub Demo1()
    With ThisWorkbook
        If Evaluate("=COUNTA('[" & .Name & "]1:9'!1:" & .Worksheets("1").Rows.Count & ")") = 0 Then
            MsgBox "All Sheets empty!"
        Else
            MsgBox "All Sheets NOT empty!"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

If sheets "1" to "9" are NOT adjacent, or have other sheets in between, use:
(or just use this version anyway)

```
Sub Demo2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tot As Long
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))
        tot = tot + WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Cells)
    Next
    If tot = 0 Then
        MsgBox "All Sheets empty!"
    Else
        MsgBox "All Sheets NOT empty!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

for some reason, i am able to check if sheet is empty if i just use "Cells". Don't know why this works as its not referencing any of the grouped sheets. May fail if other workbooks are also open.

```
Sub SheetsEmpty()
With ThisWorkbook
    ' check if sheets are empty.
    .Sheets(Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")).Select
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells) = 0 Then Exit Sub
End With
End Sub
```

if i add a Watch to this "WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells)" in watch window, it shows only a single count of cells that are non-empty and not for all 9 sheets. I guess that is because the sheets are grouped.

any ideas on this behaviour?

Comment: Please don't post updates to your question as answers.  _Edit_ your question instead.